# How to insert html cell value using xslt?

Tags: xslt-1.0

In below Code I have xml input which shows booktypes.I want to arrange book types according to there types in each columns. Some columns have values some not. Check expected output.

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <BookTypes>    
        <Types>
          <string>T1</string>
          <string>T3,M1,P1</string>
          <string>T2,P2</string>
          <string>M3,P3</string>      
        </Types>    
      </BookTypes>
```

XSLT script: Current xslt script gives me result but not as expected.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="types">
    <type>T</type>
    <type>M</type>
    <type>P</type>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="types-set" select="exsl:node-set($types)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
       <tr>
            <th>T Type</th>
            <th>M Type</th>
            <th>P Type</th>
          </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="BookTypes/Types/string">
       <tr>
          <xsl:variable name="splitValue">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($splitValue)/*">
            <xsl:variable name="mySplittedValue" select="." />
                  <xsl:for-each select="$types-set/type">
                   <xsl:variable name="my-types" select="." />
                    <td>
                       <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains($mySplittedValue, $my-types)">
                                 <xsl:value-of select="$mySplittedValue"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>

          </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
     </table>            
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
      <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
      </item>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>T Type</th>
      <th>M Type</th>
      <th>P Type</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>T1</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>T3</td>
      <td>M1</td>
      <td>P1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>T2</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>P2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>M3</td>
      <td>P3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Summery: Output
There are three(3) fixed types, P, M, T which are exist in any one input say P3, M3. here P3 contains P (type) so value P3 should come under column name P type. In input there are 3 or 2 or 1 value separed by , comma (say T3,M1,P1). That every value should be split first and then later display in table

Comment: Which specific XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: With regard to your edited (2nd) output. An example is not enough to explain the logic behind the transformation. Please provide an exact rule - for example: the first character of the string, or ... ?

Comment: There are three(3) fixed types, P, M, T which are exist in any one input say P3, M3. here P3 contains P (type) so value P3 should come under column name P type. In input there are 3 or 2 or 1 value separed by , comma (say  <string>T3,M1,P1</string>). That every value should be split first and then later display in table according to their types.

Comment: @michael I have updated your script and uploaded in my question. Execute it and check its output which may understand very easily such that you can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more complicated that it needs to be. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="types">
    <type>T</type>
    <type>M</type>
    <type>P</type>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="types-set" select="exsl:node-set($types)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="$types-set/type">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' Type')"/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="BookTypes/Types/string">
            <xsl:variable name="my-types" select="." />
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$types-set/type">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains($my-types, .)">
                                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </table>            
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>T Type</th>
      <th>M Type</th>
      <th>P Type</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>-</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>P</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>P</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>P</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Answer is correct but not work with my scenario. If I consider 2nd input format it will not work.M, P I had given just to ease you, not actual input. say You can consider input M,P etc are IPaddresses.

Comment: @ADP We can only answer the question you ask, the way you ask them. If your scenario is different, then edit your question and explain how.

Comment: I am expecting "2nd expected output" for 2nd input. please check details again.provided input values comes with M,P,T attached.

Comment: you have printed Type, But I want to print value which contains types say(M1, P1, 45P, 2M9).Types M, P and T are fixed. The value which contains any one type, that should come under type value. say M1 value should contains under M type column. In one row there are max three value separated by couma(,). I want to print each value by there types.

Comment: <xsl:when test="contains($my-types, .)">                                <xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:when>     here you are printing type, I want to print value from each row separated by (,)comma like 2nd expected output

Comment: Types are fixed and that are M, P, T only

Comment: @ADP Address yourself to the questions above (under your original question).

Comment: I have updated script by referring your script, please execute and check difference such that you can understand very easily.